# Carga de planilla Excel GX16: evitar timeout al cargar muchos registros

Tags: genexus

Tengo un procedimiento para cargar datos a través de una planilla xlxs. Tengo un problema de time out cuando quiero cargar muchos registros.

En este caso tengo una planilla con 54000: hasta los 3100 va bien, luego me tira el error de time out.

¿Cómo puedo controlar eso para que no me tire ese error?

```
do while &termino = false   
        If null(&Excel.Cells(&fila,1).Text) Or  &Excel.Cells(&fila,1).Number.IsEmpty()
           &termino = true  // Cuando llega a un registro en blanco, termina
        else    

             
            //Proceso datos de la planilla cargada 
            &Codigo = &Excel.Cells(&fila,1).Text.ToString()
            &ProductoRepetido = &Excel.Cells(&fila,2).Text.ToString()
            &BarCode = &Excel.Cells(&fila,3).Text.ToString()
            &Stock = &Excel.Cells(&fila,4).Number
                
                
                For each Producto
                    where ProductoBarCode = &BarCode
                    &ProductoId = ProductoId
                    &ProductoNombre = ProductoNombre
                    &EstaEnLaBase = true 
                when none
                    &EstaEnLaBase = false 
                Endfor
                
                if &EstaEnLaBase = false 
                    AgregarProductosRepetidos(&Context.FarmaciaId, &ProductoId, &Stock, &BarCode , &ProductoRepetido, &Codigo)
                endif
            
                if not null(&BarCode) 
                    
                    
                    //Existe registro
                    ProcExisteProd(&ProductoId,&Context.FarmaciaId, &Codigo,&Existe,&ProdFarInfoCodigoBarras)
                    
                    
                    if &Existe    
                      Msg('Hay registros')
                    else
                       AgregarProductoStock(&Context.FarmaciaId, &ProductoId,&Stock,&BarCode, &ProductoNombre)
                       &Contador = &Contador + 1
                       &retorno = 1
                    Endif
                Endif
                &fila += 1
    Endif
enddo
&fila = &fila - 2
EndSub
```

Comment: Te sugiero que incluyas toda la info que pueda ser útil. Cómo está definido el procedimiento para carga? Cuál es el mensaje de error completo? Puedes [edit] todas las veces que necesites para añadir la info

Comment: Con lo fácil que era hacer clic en en enlace que te puse en el comentario :C y con lo difícil que es leer código en los comentarios :'(

Comment: Lo agrego ahí, disculpa que no estoy muy acostumbrado a esto..

Answer (score 0):

Si lo estás ejecutando vía HTTP (ejemplo: un webpanel con un call al proc) probablemente el timeout sea de la conexión HTTP.
Lo que tendrías que hacer es usar un [submit](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15386,Submit%20command) de modo tal que es un proceso independiente (no queda ligado al timeout del HTTP).

Como es "sometido" no sabes cuando termina por lo cual al finalizar tiene que enviar una notificación a algun lado (capaz con via [socket](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22442,Server.Socket%20external%20object)) o marcar en la DB o un mail, en fin, avisar que el proceso terminó de algún modo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a considerar!